# Construct a degree $n$ polynomial with roots $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n$

Tags: polynomials, roots

We have the numbers: $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n$

Show that there is a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $n$ such that $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n$ are roots of $P(x)$

Comment: Any thoughts?  Can you do it if $n=1$?  $n=2$?

Comment: n > 1 this is a assumption

Comment: Well then can you do it if $n=2, a_1=1, a_2=2$?

Comment: I can't do this :(

Comment: Use the fact that if $f(x)$ has a root $\lambda$ then $(x-\lambda)$ is a factor of $f(x)$. For example: The degree 1 polynomial $f(x) = x - a_1$ has the root $a_1$. The degree 2 polynomial $f(x) = (x - a_1)(x-a_2)$ has the roots $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**:

1. $b$ is said to be a root of a polynomial $f(x)=x-b$.
2. $a,b$ are said to be roots of a polynomial $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)$.

Does this help?

Comment: So, I have something like this: $f(x)=$ $(x - a{_1})(x - a{_2})(x-a{_3})$ $...$ $(x-a{_n})$  yes?

Comment: Absolutely right. Bang on. :-)

Comment: @Hundasse Exactly.

Comment: @Hundasse You're welcome. If you are satisfied, you can accept my answer by clicking the tick mark on the left of my answer.

Comment: @SchrodingersCar finished